# Python Selenium ошибка get - запроса

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

При выполнении операции driver.get() в половину случаев выкидывает ошибку:

```
2019-02-06 16:18:21,936 WARNING:Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FAD2BBCBE0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение',)': /session/1be2e82d9e13c670f35af1c59f78e93b/window
2019-02-06 16:18:22,939 WARNING:Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FAD2BDE3C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение',)': /session/1be2e82d9e13c670f35af1c59f78e93b/window
2019-02-06 16:18:23,941 WARNING:Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FAD2BDE128>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение',)': /session/1be2e82d9e13c670f35af1c59f78e93b/window
```

Почему это может происходить?

Comment: посмотрите логи на "конечном компьютере", там могут быть указаны причины

Comment: @Pavel, как? я же его парсю